# How to set gnome-terminal to the remove server name without touching PS1?

Tags: ssh, gnome-terminal

There are various servers with various OS, we cannot touch the PS1 of them.

There is a "sysadmin" notebook, having CentOS 6.5/GNOME, so using gnome-terminal.

We log in via SSH to the servers in gnome-terminal.

**Question:** How can we modify the given gnome-terminals name (can have several tabs) to the remote machines name?

It is working sometimes.. on ex.: Ubuntu servers, but looks like not working by default on older servers..

Comment: You mean you want to change window title?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you mean that `PS1` is set on the server to contain an escape sequence that sets the window title to the server name, and you don't want to change configuration files on the server but you don't want the tab title to change? Or is it the local configuration that you don't want to change?